# Need help with error found in home/superuser/.profile line 23

Tags: .profile

During start up, just after I log into my account, I get an error message that says:

```
Error found when loading /home/superuser/.profile:
/home/superuser/.profile line 23: export: '=': not a valid identifier
```

As a result the session will not be configured correctly. You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.

Here's the text that's located in my `/home/superuser/.profile`:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
export level = "bandit9"
level=bandit9
level=bandit13
level=bandit13
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the spaces around the assignment operator `=` in line 23:

```
export level="bandit9"
```

For further information, read the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
export level = "bandit9"
```

You shouldn't have spaces around `=`. It should be:

```
export level="bandit9"
```

Though I don't see the point - you overwrite the values of `level` immediately after.